# IntelliJ doesn't autocomplete JUnit 5 Jupiter classes

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

I have Maven imports for JUnit 5 in an IntelliJ install, and I have invalidated the cache and restarted.

IntelliJ will refuse to autocomplete (`CTRL-SPACE`) any class nor any static method belonging to classes in the `org.junit.jupiter.api.` package, unless the class' fully qualified name is spelled out. Even when writing the package for which the class belongs, will not suggest the classes of that package.

[image: attempts]

IntelliJ version is 2017.2.1. Jupiter version is 5.0.0-RC2, platform is 1.0.0-RC2.

I am unsure how to move on from here. How come this package is the only one that seems to refuse basic completion?

```
<properties>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-RC2</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-RC2</junit.platform.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Only required to run tests in an IDE that bundles an older version -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check those classes are not in exclude list in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import`

Comment: It turned out JUnit 4, JUnit 5 and TestNG were all excluded from auto-import, which is probably my doing and I don't remember myself doing this...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downgrade JUnit 5 to M4 instead of RC2. IntelliJ 2017.2 is based on JUnit 5 M4, maybe that is causing the problem you are facing.